# Trying to reverse a C string

Tags: c++, algorithm, reverse, c-strings, function-definition

I cannot use any c functions except `strlen()`, and I also cannot use strings. I have been at this for an unfortunate amount of time. I keep getting weird characters as part of the output. i.e question marks and essentially weird alt codes is what it looks like.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cstring>

using namespace std;

int lastIndexOf(const char*, char[]);
void reverse(char*);
int replace(char*, char, char);

int main() {
  int i = 0, count = 0, counter = 0, SIZE = 100;
  char charArray[SIZE];
  cout << "Enter a string of no more than 50 characters: ";
  cin.getline(charArray, SIZE);
  reverse(charArray);
}

void reverse(char s[])
{
  int n = 100;

  for (int i = 0; i < n / 2; i++) {
    swap(s[i], s[n - i - 1]);
    cout << (s[i]);
  }
}
```

I have tried several different things, `swap` function, using pointers to manually swap them with a temp variable. So I went to the internet to see what other people did, but to no avail. I am convinced there is a simple solution.

Comment: Why do you assume that user inputted exactly 100 characters?

Comment: `int n = 100;` is your bug,

Comment: Hint: you told us you're allowed to use `strlen`, but you never use it in your code! Why do you think you needed to be allowed to use that function? Where would knowing the length of the string be important? (also see the above comment).

Comment: fwiw, this isnt the simplest thing. Don't get scared because you expect stuff to be simple but you struggle. Stuff isnt simple. Only when you managed to get it working, but then anything is "simple"

Comment: Bear with me I am not very familiar with stack overflow, i dont know whether to @Yksisarvinen you or not. But the size of the c string is not given in the problem, so i just made it randomly high so i didnt have to worry about it being too big

Comment: @God_Zilla121 Why are you allowed to use `std::swap()` but not [`std::reverse()`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/reverse)? In any case, `int n = 100;` should be `int n = strlen(s);` instead. Or better, add a `size` parameter to your `reverse()` function, and then you can use `cin.gcount()` for the size, no need for `strlen()` at all

Comment: @RemyLebeau some questions are beyond my comprehension.

Comment: Some questions are beyond ALL comprehension.

Comment: I haven't coded in `C` in decades, but one of the first things you need to be constantly aware of is that strings are terminated with a null character, and if your code does not take that into account, you will see all sorts of interesting characters.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The function uses a magic number 100

```
int n = 100;
```

though in main there is a prompt to enter no more than 50 characters.

```
cout << "Enter a string of no more than 50 characters: ";
```

You need to calculate the length of the passed string by using the standard C function `strlen`.

The function can look the following way

```
char * reverse( char s[] )
{
    for ( size_t i = 0, n = std::strlen( s ); i < n / 2; i++ )
    {
        std::swap( s[i], s[n-i-1] );
    }

    return s;
}
```

Pay attention to that variable length arrays is not a standard C++ feature.

You should write

```
const size_t SIZE = 100;
char charArray[SIZE];
```